# How to retrieve ConfigurationElement using key (array key access) in ConfigurationCollection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, configuration, indexing

I need to do something like this on my custom configuration section:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mongodb"]
```

The string "mongodb" above is the key that I am using to access de element of type System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings. I wish to do the same with my custom collection:

```
[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(Question))]
public class QuestionCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{   

    public override bool IsReadOnly()
    {
        return false;
    }

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new Question();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((Question)element).id;
    }

    //Is here?
    public Question this[int idx]
    {
        get {
            return (Question)BaseGet(idx);
        }

        set
        {
            if (BaseGet(idx) != null)
                BaseRemoveAt(idx);

            BaseAdd(idx, value);
        }
    }

}
```

I was wondering that method commented above is the way to get what I want... But I don't know how.... The type of key I want use to access is integer.

Supposing I have the following configuration:

```
    <securityQuestions>
    <questions>
      <add id="3" value="What is your name?" default="true"/>
      <add id="4" value="What is your age?"/>
    </questions>
</securityQuestions>
```

How can I access the first element (id=3) with ...Section.Questions[3] (3 is not the position, but the key)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the name of Your custom config section is `SecurityQuestionsSection`.

And I assume that You have this code:

```
public class SecurityQuestionsSection: ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("questions", IsRequired = true, IsDefaultCollection = true)]
    public QuestionCollection Questions
    {
        get
        {
            return (QuestionCollection)base["questions"];
        }
    }
}
```

If so, You can write something like this:

```
var customConfigSection = (SecurityQuestionsSection)ConfigurationManager
                                        .GetSection("securityQuestionsSection");

var firstElementId = customConfigSection.Questions[0].Id;
```

Hope this helps!

**Edits:** to access config element by it's key You have two options.

1) You can use Linq outside of the class:

```
var elementWithIdOfThree = customConfigSection.Questions
                                   .FirstOrDefault(item => item.Id == 3);
```

2) Or You can add a method for it to Your QuestionCollection class like so:

```
public Question GetQuestionWithId(int id)
{
    return this.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Id == id);
}
```

Comment: Well... I have that code, but I still can't access by the key customConfigSection.Questions[<HERE_GOES_THE_KEY_NOT_POSITION>].Id;

Comment: @LucasBatistussi, You mean You want to get element with id of "3" for example?

Comment: Yes! This what I want :)

Comment: Well... I got an ugly solution.... I made the following in QuestionCollection class:                                                              public Question this[string idx]
        {
            get {

                object[] keys = this.BaseGetAllKeys();
                int IDX = int.Parse(idx);

                foreach(object i in keys){

                    if (IDX == (int)i)
                    {
                        return BaseGet(i) as Question;
                    }

                }

                return null;
            }
        }

Comment: Do you have a more elegant solution? Is there a default way by ASP.NET to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Aleksei Chepovoi for the sugestions. The solution is as follows:

```
[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(Question))]
public class QuestionCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{   

    public override bool IsReadOnly()
    {
        return false;
    }

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new Question();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((Question)element).id;
    }

    public Question this[int id]
    {
        get
        {
           return this.OfType<Question>().FirstOrDefault(item => item.id == id);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Should the signature of the indexer be:
 public new Question this[int id]?

Answer (score 3):

You can force this overload to retrieve the `configurationElement` item by its key:

```
public Question GetQuestion(int id)
{
    get
    {
       return (Question)this.BaseGet((object)id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(Question))]
public class QuestionCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{   

    public override bool IsReadOnly()
    {
        return false;
    }

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new Question();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((Question)element).id;
    }

    public Question GetQuestion(int id)
    {
        return (Question)this.BaseGet(id);
    }

}
```

Comment: If you don't want to use Linq, you can use BaseGet